How can I configure Sphinx to treat "-" as a normal symbol when searching?
I am using Sphinx for documentation, and I use a MyST Parser
My documentation is technical, so I often want to search some command line options, like for example --run. However, the "-" (dash, munis) symbols are ignored in search field, and I see lots of unrelated results with just word "run".
I also tried to use quotes, like '--run' in search, that did not help.
More of that, the "-" is treated as separator (like a space), and if I search for example --start-program, I get unrelated results with the word "starting" for example.
So the question is, how do I force Sphinx to treat the "-" just as a normal letter?

You cannot out of the box because Sphinx's default search splits on words. You can either edit and adapt the search index and results to what you desire, or use another search feature for your docs. Some use Algolia or Nuclia.

@StevePiercy Thanks, I have added the feature request here: https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/12400. If you get something to comment, please do.
